# Implementing Undo feature (like Ctrl+Z) in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, undo

I am using `Qt 4.5` and `C++` on Windows XP.

Basically I will be having an UI where the user will enter some data. He can go and modify the values available in the UI. The UI will have basic Qt UI elements like `QLineEdit`,`QTableWidget` etc.,

So now, if the user presses `Undo` button (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>) the previous value should be retained in the corresponding UI element.

Say, if there is `QLineEdit` with the text 25. Now the user modifies to 30. Now by clicking Undo, the older value 25 should be retained.

Like the Undo feature that usually available in many applications. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I edited "Back" into "Undo" which is the most typical name for this functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Qt's undo framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qundo.html).

Comment: Sorry for not explaining how to actually implement your own undo functionality. unwind's answer is much better in that regard. If you just want a quick, Qt-centric solution however, then its undo framework is probably what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The typical way of implementing Undo is to represent each action done by the user, and store them. You also want the ability to compute the inverse of a given action.

So, for an insert into a text buffer, the action would store the text inserted, and the location at which the insert happened. The inverse then becomes a delete, at the same location and with the size of the inserted text.

When the user asks the application to undo, simply look at the most recent stored action, and execute its inverse. If you now instead of deleting the "spent" action remember it, too,  you can implement Redo by moving the other way in the history of actions.

Note that this is an abstract and generic explanation; as other answers point out, Qt has a framwork in place for implementing Undo already, so you should of course investigate that, first.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to realize undo/redo

Answer (score 1):

QLineEdit has a built-in undo/redo support, exported as public slots, check : http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlineedit.html#undo